# Using Report (Reporting Services) parameter values in ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, report

I have a report (Reporting Services) integrated into an ASP.NET that shows dropdownlists to select report parameter values. The dropdownlists are populated using direct database selects, though I see the report RDL files do contain the paramter values and datasets as defined in the report designer.

Is it possible to obtain the report parameters "available values" in ASP.NET to populate the dropdownlists? This would avoid some code duplication.

**Update**

If the parameter doesn't use a query for available values, the following works:

```
foreach (ValidValue value in this.ReportViewerControl.ServerReport.GetParameters()["myParameter"].ValidValues) {
    this.DropDownListControl.Items.Add(new ListItem(value.Label, value.Value));
}
```

Still haven't found a way to access report datasets though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is not any way for doing this work.